# Assign Id to include tag with layout having merge as root item

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have defined the following layout for app's toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupMenuOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</merge>
```

I include it in any other layout using `include` tag like following;

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_wrapper"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>
```

As this tag is in `Relative layout`, I have assigned it an `ID` to add more items under the toolbar. Everything works fine (views are added below the toolbar) but when I open `view hierarchy`, I can see `toolbar view` with id `toolbar` but

> **I can't see `toolbar_wrapper` id, assigned to `AppBarLayout`.**

Is this the right behavior? I suspect, I am missing something here.

**Where is the id I have assigned to include tag?**

[image: Snapshot of view heirarchy]

Comment: I have the exact same problem and to make things worse this trips up ViewBinding because it won't find the ID of the include tag which uses the merge. The only solution I found is to forego the advantages the `<merge>` gives us and just add another dummy ViewGroup inside the includable layout